# -r filename && . filename

Tags: shell, shell-script

i was just looking into a script i find this line. can anyone tell me what this line do. this is the code line.

```
[ -r "$PosConfigDir/posconfig.sh" ] && . "$PosConfigDir/posconfig.sh"
```

Answer (score 6):

It checks whether you have permission to `r`ead the file `$PosConfigDir/posconfig.sh`, after symlink resolution, then [sources](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18) that file.

It does not guarantee that you can read the file. For example, on most systems, `[ -r / ]` would return true but you cannot [read](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) `/`.

`-r` is a [standard test operator](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_05).

[`.`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18) is a special builtin command of Bourne-like shells that tells the shell to read and interpret the code in the file given as argument. `source` is the equivalent command in `csh`. Many modern Bourne-like shells understand `source` as an alias for `.`.

With some shell implementations, the failure of `.` to open or read the file would cause the shell to abort (after having output an error message). The `-r` check is presumably meant to prevent that in that case.

To prevent the shell from aborting, in POSIX shells, an alternative could be

```
 command . "$PosConfigDir/posconfig.sh"
```

(Though the above construct won't work in `zsh` unless in `sh` or `ksh` emulation)

To avoid the error message, you'd need to redirect the stderr output to `/dev/null`, but that would have the unwanted side-effect of also silencing the errors of the commands in `postconfig.sh`.

An example:

```
$ [ -r /etc/os-release ] && . /etc/os-release
$ printf '%s\n' "$PRETTY_NAME"
Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)
```

`PRETTY_NAME` was defined in `/etc/os-release` file:

```
$ head -n 1 /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
```

Comment: oh it means if that file is readable then use some of the functionality from that file. right!

Comment: @TheBharat: Yes, read more about [dot](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18) command.

Comment: Note that `-r` only checks that you have _permission_ to read the file (after symlink resolution). That doesn't guarantee that you'll be able to read it. For instance, `[ -r / ]` returns true, but on most systems, you won't be able to `read(2)` `/` (`.` would still fail).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, updated the answer. I remembered you have noticed me before, just don't have time to update the answer. Is it better now

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: `command .` does not work with `zsh` unless in `sh` or `ksh` emulation.